# How to merge files into one with break line?

Tags: linux, cat

I have files in a directory:

```
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt
```

One line per file and there is no break line at the end of each file. How to merge those files into one with a break line at the end of each file?

If I run:

```
cat 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 123.txt
```

The files are merged, but all content becomes one line, due to the fact that there is no break line in the original lines. How to add break each line in the merging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo > /tmp/line
cat 1.txt /tmp/line 2.txt /tmp/line 3.txt /tmp/line > 123.txt
```

Or:

```
{ cat 1.txt && echo && cat 2.txt && echo && cat 3.txt && echo; } > 123.txt
```

Or:

```
awk '{print}' {1,2,3}.txt > 123.txt
```

Or:

```
grep -h '' {1..3}.txt > 123.txt
```

Or:

```
cut -c 1- 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt > 123.txt
```

Or:

```
sed '' *.txt > 123.txt
```

Practically any line-oriented text filter will do, because they all know how to deal with files lacking newlines at the end.  Only `cat` is so simple as to not do what you want (partly because people use it for data which is not text).

Comment: what's "echo>/tmp/line"? can i use any directory?

Comment: @user697911: `/tmp/line` is just a temporary file I made up.  You can put it in the current directory or any other place.